# Hooking loaded dlls (Vs C++)

Tags: c++, dll, c++14

I've managed to rebuild an old project but one of the loaded .dlls fails at some point:

```
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Disk_D_Backup\Projects\zynaddsubfx\build\src\Release\zynaddsubfx.exe'. Module was built without symbols.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Disk_D_Backup\Projects\zynaddsubfx\build\src\Release\liblo.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Disk_D_Backup\Projects\zynaddsubfx\build\src\Release\mxml1.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Disk_D_Backup\Projects\zynaddsubfx\build\src\Release\libfftw3-3.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Disk_D_Backup\Projects\zynaddsubfx\build\src\Release\pthreadVC2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'zynaddsubfx.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Disk_D_Backup\Projects\zynaddsubfx\build\src\Release\pthreadVC2.dll'
The thread 0x3e94 has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
The thread 0x5f70 has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
The program '[9824] zynaddsubfx.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
```

Looking at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/run-time-library-behavior?view=msvc-160

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-from-a-dll-project?view=vs-2019

is there an easier way to see where the threads in these dlls crash without debugging them separately?

Fortunately, they're open source but it seems like a lot of headaches.

I tried setting up a breakpoint on main() but execution ends before it gets there. The dlls as well as the exe are all x64/release.

Comment: `0xc000007b` means invalid image format. Are you mixing 32 and 64 bit (not sure if that is the correct error code for that)?

Comment: I wrongly copied a Debug version of liblo ...